# how to decode/decrypt a license for visual studio professional in powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 Professional with a license key. From my search, I have found out that the license is stored in the registry key instance as well.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\73A4C9C1-D68D-11d0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9
```

However, it looks like the value is encrypted and I want to create a Powershell script to decrypt it.

Any advise, please?

Comment: You can't without the private key.

Comment: If you installed it with a license key, shouldn't you have said license key to have been able to install it?

Comment: @jdweng where can I find the key?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician idk what you mean. Basically, I want to deploy the ps script to track the license status of all VS Pro installed on each machine under the same domain. The output from the script I am expecting is 'Machine Name', 'License Value', and 'Licensed'. I searched and it looks like the vs license is subscription based. Now I doubt it is even possible...

Comment: You can't.  Vendor encryption is proprietary so somebody cannot use application without a license.

Comment: @jdweng yeah it looks like its impossible. Thank you tho!